# CORS policy Error after publising the Angular App and ASPNET Core To IIS

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I have an Angular app and API end point with ASPNET Core 3.1
I published these two apps under IIS
I open the Cors in Back-End like so at **ConfigureService**

```
services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
        {
            builder
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .SetIsOriginAllowed(_ => true)
                .AllowCredentials();
        }));
```

And in **Configure** like that:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        //Localization
        app.UseRequestLocalization();

        app.UseRouting();

        // global cors policy
        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

        app.UseStaticFiles(); // For the wwwroot folder

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapHub<NotifyHub>("/notify");
        });
    }
```

In my Angualr App I put all the setting in the

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  isMockEnabled: false, // You have to switch this, when your real back-end is done,
  url: 'http://localhost:8083/api/',
  signalr_url: 'http://localhost:8083/notify',
  header: { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } },
  debugMode: false,
  app_url: 'http://localhost:80/'
};
```

in IIS my port for API is **localhost:8083** and for front-end (Angular) is **localhost:80**

after all of that I received the CORS error

Comment: If you enabled other authentication modes in IIS, such as windows authentication, we had better install the IIS Cors module to support CORS. You could refer to the document.
https://blogs.iis.net/iisteam/getting-started-with-the-iis-cors-module

Answer (score 0):

Can you use your code something like below? May be this technique might help you!

In `ConfigureServices()` method:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
   ...
   services.AddCors();
   ...
  }
```

In `Configure()` method:

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
  {
   ...
   app.UseCors(builder =>
          builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
          .AllowAnyHeader()
          .AllowAnyMethod()
        );
   ...
  }
```